# price help turn pounds into pence

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, currency

I am working with codeigniter and i need to change 2.50 into 250 or 300.70 into 30070, basically, I need send PAYPAL my price in pence and not pounds, how do I change it so my price reads in pence and not pounds?

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? (Presumably "multiply by 100" is not a useful answer?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The following code will convert pounds to pence:

```
$pence = $pounds * 100;
```

It really is that simple. [Google](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&source=hp&q=convert+pence+to+pounds&pbx=1&oq=convert+pence+to+pounds&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=5797l6578l1l6797l8l6l0l0l0l5l203l750l1.3.1l5l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=1350c3a2e903cb66&biw=1680&bih=883) will confirm it. It's analogous to converting dollars to pennies.

Comment: You may also need to clean up any decimal place to get a whole number only with round() and/or intval(). I needed this when accepting user input since users could input something silly like £53.349.

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by 100 - moves the decimal two places